# Having a Neural Network recreate what it's learned

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pattern-recognition, image-processing

I've created a basic Neural Network that learns from basic information and can verify whether or not a piece of information matches it's parameters from a match percentage. Conceptually however, I haven't been able to think of or find anything on google about actually compiling something new. For instance, if I where to feed my network hundreds of images of dogs, It can recognize a dog, but it can't draw a dog. It definitely doesn't have to be accurate, but how could I have the network in this example draw a dog? Would I simply do something like drawing the highest weighted nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard feed forward network is conceptually not meant to generate samples. It is a discriminative model.
There are, however, generative models like restricted Boltzmann machines that allow you to generate samples.

That being said, it's not completely impossible to get something sample-like from a feed forward neural network.
You could fix the output of the model and also keep all the weights fixed and then optimize for the inputs. 
If it's a binary classifier, dog=1 vs not-dog=0, you could fix the output to one and do your usual backprop-gradient descent but instead of optimizing the weights you only optimize for the network's input. That will give you input values that will lead to a high score for the classifier and if the network was trained properly it might look like a dog.

Maybe you can get some inspiration from
[Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks
by Zeiler et al.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901v3.pdf)

Comment: Would this be a possible application for evolutionary algorithms?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you would want to apply evolutionary algorithms in this setting? What would your fitness be, what would your input/pool be?

Comment: fitness would be the validity as determined by the neural network, input would be random at first, evolving to fit the network's parameters.

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you mean by "evolving to fit the network's parameters".
If you are thinking of using genetic (?) algorithms to optimize the neural network input such that it produces a high score for "dog", sure, you could probably do that.
However, you have a gradient with respect to the inputs of the network. Using that for gradient descent will most likely lead to much much faster convergence and much lower training time until you have a usable sample.